# MySQL time duration format, import from CSV

Tags: mysql, excel, csv, sqldatatypes

**What's wrong?**

- A new column (in Excel) was made for calculating Duration

  - Using formula to subtract values from 2 cells
  - For example: `2021-01-01 07:30 - 2021-01-01 07:00; Duration = 00:30:00`
- In MySQL table, I set the data type for the column as `TIME`, but it would return with error when importing

  - Error message: '`Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '00:13:00 ' for column 'ride_length`'

**What I have tried:**

- Changing data type to `DATETIME`, `INT`, `TIME` -> None worked
- Changing the data format to `HH:MM:SS`, `HHMMSS`, 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:MM:SS' in CSV -> None worked

**Question**

- What kind of `data type` I should set in MySQL?
- If it was the CSV file's problem, what kind of 'data format' I need to set?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you give an example of not working data, and the code you are using?

Comment: Provide complete CREATE TABLE script, CSV file content (2-3 rows) and SQL query which is used for importing. In general there is no any problem in TIME data importing.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it might be easier for you to just import the two datetime values and then use `TIMSTAMPDIFF` inside MySQL:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, '2021-01-01 07:00:00', '2021-01-01 07:30:00')
-- 30
```

Note that because the difference is actually a computed quantity, it generally makes more sense to compute it when you select.  This way, should one of the two values be updated later, you don't have to worry about maintaining the difference column.

Comment: Thanks Tim for explaining and the suggestion!!
Is there a function in SQL that can subtract like Excel (cell by cell), I got more than 200,000 rows in the dataset.....

Could be a stupid question, SQL newbie here

Comment: SQL queries are set based operations.  The query in my answer will work on all your data in one go.